# Can TInterlocked.CompareExchange() support an interfaced object?

Tags: delphi, thread-safety

I have a lazy create situation where a (singleton) object is only created if code executes that needs it. This is operating in the context of an ISAPI dll, which is multi-threaded, so there is a risk that two threads could access it.

My code initially looked like this, quite naive:

```pascal
...
interface

var
  FHIRResourceFactory: function: IFHIRResourceFactory;

implementation
...
// global var and function
var
  _FHIRFactory: IFHIRResourceFactory;

function GetFHIRResourceFactory: IFHIRResourceFactory;
begin
  if (_FHIRFactory = nil) then
    { The object doesn't exist yet. Create one. }
    _FHIRFactory := TFHIRResourceFactory.Create;
  Result := _FHIRFactory;
end;

initialization

FHIRResourceFactory := GetFHIRResourceFactory;
end.
```

I refactored it to use `AtomicCmpExchange()`, but I find that the created object falls out of scope:

```pascal
...
interface

var
  FHIRResourceFactory: function: IFHIRResourceFactory;

implementation
...
// global var and function
var
  _FHIRFactory: IFHIRResourceFactory;

function GetFHIRResourceFactory: IFHIRResourceFactory;
var
  newFHIRFactory: IFHIRResourceFactory;
begin
  if (_FHIRFactory = nil) then
  begin
    { The object doesn't exist yet. Create one. }
    newFHIRFactory := TFHIRResourceFactory.Create;
    { It's possible another thread also created one.
      Only one of us will be able to set the _FHIRFactory singleton variable }
   if AtomicCmpExchange(Pointer(_FHIRFactory), Pointer(newFHIRFactory), nil) <>= nil then
    begin
      { The other beat us. Destroy our newly created object and use theirs. }
      newFHIRFactory := nil;
    end;
// if I don't add this line the object will fall out of scope and be destroyed
//      _FHIRFactory._AddRef
  end;
  Result := _FHIRFactory;
end;

initialization

FHIRResourceFactory := GetFHIRResourceFactory;
end.
```

Is there a version of `TInterlocked.CompareExchange()` that can accept Interfaced objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `TInterlocked` *does not* have any support for handling reference-counted interfaces (oddly, its `TObject` methods *do* handle reference-counted objects under ARC systems). So, you have to manage interface reference counts manually.

For example, this is the function that is used by Indy:

```pascal
function InterlockedCompareExchangeIntf(var VTarget: IInterface; const AValue, Compare: IInterface): IInterface;
  {$IFDEF USE_INLINE}inline;{$ENDIF}
begin
  // TInterlocked does not have an overload for IInterface.
  // We have to ensure that the reference counts of the interfaces are managed correctly...
  if AValue <> nil then begin
    AValue._AddRef;
  end;
  Result := IInterface(InterlockedCompareExchangePtr(Pointer(VTarget), Pointer(AValue), Pointer(Compare)));
  if (AValue <> nil) and (Pointer(Result) <> Pointer(Compare)) then begin
    AValue._Release;
  end;
end;
```

(where `InterlockedCompareExchangePtr()` is a wrapper for various platform-specific functions, including `TInterlocked.CompareExchange()` when available)

You can replace `InterlockedCompareExchangePtr()` with the `AtomicCmpExchange()` that you are already using, or the `Pointer` overload of `TInterlocked.CompareExchange()`.

For example:

```
function GetFHIRResourceFactory: IFHIRResourceFactory;
var
  newFHIRFactory: IFHIRResourceFactory;
begin
  if (_FHIRFactory = nil) then
  begin
    { The object doesn't exist yet. Create one. }
    newFHIRFactory := TFHIRResourceFactory.Create;
    { It's possible another thread also created one.
      Only one of us will be able to set the _FHIRFactory singleton variable }
    newFHIRFactory._AddRef;
    if (TInterlocked.CompareExchange(Pointer(_FHIRFactory), Pointer(newFHIRFactory), nil) <> nil then begin
      { The other beat us. Destroy our newly created object and use theirs. }
      newFHIRFactory._Release;
    end;
  end;
  Result := _FHIRFactory;
end;
```

If `_FHIRFactory` gets set to the new object, its recount will have been incremented to 2, and is then decremented to 1 when `newFHIRFactory` goes out of scope, thus leaving the object alive.

If `_FHIRFactory` does not get set to the new object, its recount will have been incremented to 2 and then back to 1, and is then decremented to 0 when `newFHIRFactory` goes out of scope, destroying the object.

Comment: That's a nice implementation thank you. The _AddRef and _Release makes more sense than my original.
And I will take a look at the code you've shown from Indy as there are a few similar code instances in this project.